# How can I control Banshee

Tags: banshee, menu

I just started using Banshee (in fact, just started using Ubuntu), and cannot figure out how to control Banshee. I have no menu bar. I read instructions on the internet about how to click on Media, or click on Help, and so on, but I have no "media" or "help" to click on. Just a bare interface. I can close it, and I can open it, but can't do anything else with the music player.

Comment: I took a shot at answering your question, but if that doesn't help, it would be useful to see a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu hides the menu bar behind the title in the panel at the very top of the screen.  When you mouse over that area, menu items such as "Media" and "Edit" should become available.

From there, you'll be able to import your music via Media > Import.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent about an hour playing around with Banshee, but never moved the cursor all the way to the top of the screen. Recently I discovered I could get to the menu bar, but only if Banshee was in full screen mode, and I was using in as a reduced size panel. This will help immensely.